# Is there a way to flush html to the wire in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app with a long running process (a web scraper). I'd like the app flush the results of the crawler's progress as the crawler is running instead of at the end.

I've considered forking the request and doing something fancy with ajax but this is a really basic one-pager app that really just needs to output a log to a browser as it's happening. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update (2012-03-21)

As of Sinatra 1.3.0, you can use the new streaming API:

```
get '/' do
  stream do |out|
    out << "foo\n"
    sleep 10
    out << "bar\n"
  end
end
```

### Old Answer

Unfortunately you don't have a stream you can simply flush to (that would not work with Rack middleware). The result returned from a route block can simply respond to `each`. The Rack handler will then call `each` with a block and in that block flush the given part of the body to the client.

All rack responses have to always respond to `each` and always hand strings to the given block. Sinatra takes care of this for you, if you just return a string.

A simple streaming example would be:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  result = ["this", " takes", " some", " time"]
  class << result
    def each
      super do |str|
        yield str
        sleep 0.3
      end
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Now you could simply place all your crawling in the `each` method:

```
require 'sinatra'

class Crawler
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def each
    yield "opening url\n"
    result = open @url
    yield "seaching for foo\n"
    if result.include? "foo"
      yield "found it\n"
    else
      yield "not there, sorry\n"
    end
  end
end

get '/' do
  Crawler.new 'http://mysite'
end
```

Comment: hi, I'm a little confused here. How many times is the :each called in Crawler class by rack. How do we control that?

Comment: Usually it's called once (when streaming out), but middleware might call it, too, to get access to the body content, so you cannot be 100% sure it's only being called once. Also keep in mind that this does not flush on Thin.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the new streaming API.