# Streaming data from Sinatra/Rack application

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I am trying to stream textual data (XML/JSON) from a Ruby (1.9.1p378) Sinatra (1.0) Rack (1.2.1) application. The suggested solutions (e.g. [Is there a way to flush html to the wire in Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027435/is-there-a-way-to-flush-html-to-the-wire-in-sinatra)) do not seem to work - the server just blocks when I yield elements of some infinite stream (e.g. from `%w(foo bar).cycle`). I tried `webrick` and `thin` as servers.

Any suggestions on getting this done? Should I use http://sinatra.rubyforge.org/api/classes/Sinatra/Streaming.html and if so how would I use it in my application?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Neither Webrick nor Thin support streaming that way. You could try Mongrel or Unicorn. If you want to use Thin or Rainbows!, you have to hook into the event loop in order to achieve streaming:

```
require 'sinatra'

class Stream
  include EventMachine::Deferrable
  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end

  def each(&block)
    if @counter > 10
      succeed
    else
      EM.next_tick do
        yield counter
        each(&block)
      end
    end
  end
end

get '/' do
  Stream.new
end
```

I recently wrote a EventSource implementation that way:

```
require 'sinatra'

class EventStream
  include EventMachine::Deferrable
  def each
    count = 0
    timer = EventMachine::PeriodicTimer.new(1) do
      yield "data: #{count += 1}\n\n"
    end
    errback { timer.cancel }
  end
end

get '/' do
  EventMachine.next_tick do
    request.env['async.callback'].call [
      200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream'},
      EventStream.new ]
  end
  [-1, {}, []]
end
```

If you want to use Webrick for Streaming: [here](http://rack.lighthouseapp.com/projects/22435/tickets/39-patch-streaming-of-response-bodies-under-webrick) is a patch.

Comment: Thin has the advantage of being able to answer other requests while streaming.

Answer (score 31):

Starting with Sinatra 1.3, you could also use the new streaming API:

```
get '/evented' do
  stream(:keep_open) do |out|
    EventMachine::PeriodicTimer.new(1) { out << "#{Time.now}\n" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Konstantin - does this work with ALL web servers or just evented web servers like Thin? I'm having trouble tracking down example code for the new streaming API that use a standard server like Passenger...

Comment: Only with evented web servers, like Thin, Rainbows! or Ebb - but Puma is planning to support this.

Comment: Streaming without `:keep_open` works on all servers, but will not stream on all (namely not on Webrick).

Comment: If you tell it to keep open, how can you close it? I.e., I want to keep it open until I've piped over all my content, then close.

Answer (score 7):

As Colin mentioned, Goliath can stream response data, as well as incoming (large file uploads). There is an example in the repo for streaming data to the client: https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath/blob/master/examples/stream.rb

Instead of a timer, you can easily hook up any other data stream to push data to the client. For example, you can connect an AMQP queue, or any other message queue directly to Goliath and let it act as an HTTP frontend to that data.

Comment: Is there already a community for goliath somewhere? The whole project seems to be pretty much bleeding edge and I am quite unsure about a few things like support for chunking and the identification of requests in callbacks ...

Comment: The mailing list is a great place to start: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/goliath-io - there is a good group of people watching it. Some of the more interesting apps that are being built with Goliath are unfortunately not in the public, but that will change with time. It is bleeding edge. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely take a look at the rack-able [Goliath web server](http://www.igvita.com/2011/03/08/goliath-non-blocking-ruby-19-web-server/). It supports streaming out-of-the-box. I am using it for a firehose style streaming api.

> Goliath is both an app server and a
>   lightweight framework designed to meet
>   the following goals: fully
>   asynchronous processing, middleware
>   support, simple configuration,
>   high-performance, and arguably most
>   importantly, readable and maintainable
>   code.

Comment: Very interesting project! Thanks hint!