# HTML5 Server-Sent Events with Ruby Sinatra

Tags: ruby, html, sinatra, server-sent-events

I'm new to Ruby and Sinatra, I'm trying to setup a simple HTML5 Server-Sent Event with it, The code below works fine in Chrome developer builds but fails in Non Developer Builds and Safari on both Windows7 and OSX.

The error message in the browser console is "Failed to load resource: cancelled"

```
 var source = new EventSource('pull');
        source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);

        }, false);

        source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
            // Conn open
        }, false);

        source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
            if (e.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) {
                // Connection was closed.
            }
        }, false);
```

With the below Sinatra route

```
get '/pull' do
   content_type 'text/event-stream'
   newevent   = false
   response = "data: "+newevent.inspect+" \n\n"
end
```

I have tried similar server side code with JSP and Tomcat and it works fine on all browser.

What do I need to know about Sinatra?
thanks!

Comment: Figured out, I wasnt setting the right response headers, seems like Chrome Dev is more relaxed when it comes to headers.
The headers below worked ..

response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'

Comment: That will only return one value and close the connection. What's the advantage over AJAX then?

Answer (score 26):

If you want to support events, you have to [create your own body object](https://github.com/rkh/presentations/blob/realtime-rack/example.rb). Take a look at at [the implementation](https://github.com/rkh/presentations/blob/realtime-rack/example.rb#L9-24) and [usage](https://github.com/rkh/presentations/blob/realtime-rack/example.rb#L51-57). Make sure you run it with Thin or Rainbows. It will not work on Mongrel or WEBrick.

You can watch the [presentation at Confreaks](http://confreaks.net/videos/727-rockymtnruby2011-real-time-rack) (its [source code at GitHub](https://github.com/rkh/presentations/tree/realtime-rack)).

Update: Here is [one more example](https://gist.github.com/1476463) (Simple Chat Application using the Sinatra Streaming API).

Comment: Konstantin, how would you remove closed connections from the list of subscribers? Chrome closes EventSource connection after 60 sec and opens a new one, so that the list is growing. Is there a way to set an infinite timeout for EventSource similar to WebSocket?

Comment: Konstantin replied: You can add a `callback/errback` to the body object. You can send null bytes or empty messages if nothing happened within 60 seconds (use EventMachine's timeout events for this).

Comment: See [Writing Good Link Text](http://www.yorku.ca/webacces/simplestrategies/10_linktext.html), "here" is **not** good link text.

Comment: More answers and comments on Sinatra with [event streaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669674/streaming-data-from-sinatra-rack-application) and [WebSockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999430/any-success-with-sinatra-working-together-with-eventmachine-websockets)