# How to stream big files (like CSV/XML) in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Rails 3.0 it was possible to stream big files, like CSV or XML, with the self.response_body hack.

Rails 3.1 killed this feature and added streaming. Only that streaming doesn't seem to work, or there isn't documentation on how to send large files. I tried with partials, without partials, with html.erb view instead of csv.erb, and nothing works.

How can you stream large files in rails 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use Apache/Phusion passenger, have you tried using the rack-based **[x-sendfile](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file)** ?

**EDIT**: more info **[here](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Sendfile.html)**

Comment: The CSV/XML files are generated by Rails on demand. So they should be streamed as they are generated.

Comment: don't know if it can help, but i found **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669674/streaming-data-from-sinatra-rack-application)** and **[this](https://github.com/aniero/rack-streaming-proxy)**. Still think that rack is the direction to look at.

Comment: thanks for all the replies. I'm looking for a Rails 3.1 specific solution. 3.1 added streaming, and I was able to this before.