# Streaming JSON in Rails 3.2 (Unicorn server) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, streaming

We are trying to stream large data as JSON in Rails 3.2. Rails out of the box streaming works only for partials and hence we decided to generate JSON as text. As suggested in other posts, I created a Stream class with each method and did a "yield" for every object.

Unicorn server is not sending any response for 3 mins and then sends all the data back.

- Does streaming working in Unicorn server?
- How do I force flush the output?

We are hosting this server behind ELB and the request times out after 60 seconds.

**Controller Method**

```
def listings
   self.response_body = Stream.new Listing
end
```

**Stream class**

```
class Stream
  def initialize collection
    @collection = collection
  end

  def each
    size = @collection.count
    index = 0
    yield "["
    @collection.find_each do |obj|
       yield (size - 1 == index) ? obj.to_json : "#{obj.to_json},"
       index += 1
    end
    yield "]"
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream console output through HTTP (with Ruby)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684784/stream-console-output-through-http-with-ruby)