# How can I echo the output from Ruby shell scripts in chunks?

Tags: ruby, shell, sinatra

I'm setting up a mini deploy system with Ruby and Sinatra and Shell scripts, and when I trigger a deploy script I'd like ruby to continue to echo the output from the following:

```
post '/' do
  `/home/deploy/deploy.sh`
end
```

How can I ensure that Ruby will echo the output and send a chunked response (so that the content can continue to load)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two distinct problems here:

1. *How to stream-receive the output of the command while it is running?*

   - You want to use [`IO.popen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen).
2. Within Sinatra, how do I stream a response to the user?

   - You want to use [Sinatra 1.3's `stream`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra#Streaming_Responses). (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669674/streaming-data-from-sinatra-rack-application).)

Comment: Interesting, I've seen many developers moving from backticks to popen. Thanks for the tip! I wouldn't have found `::Streaming`

Comment: @DeLongey Sorry, ::Streaming is for binary/file sends. See my updated answer for how to stream response to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I would have found out the hard way ;)